# keepalived cannot receive multicast packet on bond(m=1) interface but tcpdump can result in keepalived both enter master

Tags: linux, network-programming, multicast, high-availability

I have two linux server,

Each server have two NICs with mode 1 bonding "bond0".

My user level app - keepalived run VRRP instance on this bonding interface with keepalived keywords "interface bond0" specified on each server.

Each server also specified "state BACKUP" and different priority.

But two server both enter MASTER.

I find some exception one server in lower priority:

1. tcpdump shows it send out vrrp adv.
2. tcpdump shows it also receive vrrp adv from another server with higher priority.
3. strace shows receive timeout and sendmsg(vrrp) successfully.

Any suggestion can help me to find the root cause? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Resolved.

rpf in route system drop the packet because source address reason.